# Why is MSG command not working in IF statement?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything on this specifically.  I'm a beginner at batch / CMD so this may be obvious.

The MSG command works fine in other batch scripts that I've written.  But I'm writing a batch file that starts as below.  (I've replaced the "magick" command with "testcommand" while testing.)

```
@echo off

REM ### check that the Image Magick program is installed
WHERE testcommand >nul 2>nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO magick wasn't found 
    MSG You need to install ImageMagick
    PAUSE
    )
```

This should send a warning to the window and also show a popup alert using the MSG command.  However, the output I get is:

```
magick wasn't found
you does not exist or is disconnected
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why isn't the MSG command working?  Do I need to escape the previous command?  I've tried putting the text in quotes etc but there's no change.

Comment: Aside from the information you have received in the existing answer, you should also take a look at the usage information for the where.exe utility, `where /?`. It has a `/Q` option which would be useful to you. 1. `@%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /Q "FileNameWithOutExtensionListedUnderPATHEXT-or-FileNameWithExtension"`, 
2. `@If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo Not Found)`. Please also be aware that this alone does not indicate whether the program is installed, it only tells you if a file matching yours is located in the current directory, or a location listed within `%PATH%`.

Comment: @5Diraptor Your message is not true. The command `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe` available since Windows Server 2003 and Windows Vista (by default not on Windows XP) does not check if *ImageMagick* is installed or not, it just checks if the executable of *ImageMagick* can be found using the __local__ environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`. That are two different things. BTW: The name of this application suite is `ImageMagick` (without a space) and __not__ `Image Magick` (with space) and also __not__ `magick` (incomplete and first character wrong).

Comment: The help syntax for the `MSG` command clearly shows that you need to supply one of these options at a minimum. **MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}**

Comment: @mofi, in the live script I intend to replace `testcommand` with `magick` as this is the correct function name to start imagemagick.  I won't be testing for the executable file for imagemagick.  Is that ok?

Comment: This page details command line usage of the `magick` program - https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php

Comment: @5Diraptor, the `WHERE` command does not test the functionality of `magick` being able to execute.  As has already been stated it just validates that a file named `magick` is located somewhere in your path.

Comment: @squashman I think I understand what you're saying, but is there an actual issue with this test, or is it just that my comments aren't completely accurate?  Generally speaking, I thought the command `magick ` will only be in my Environment Variables path if ImageMagick is installed properly?  I get that users can custom install stuff and mess things up, but I'm just looking for a basic level of error checking here.  Would it be better to run a command such as `magick -version` and test if that outputs a valid result?

Comment: I have been programming for 40 years.  I have a set of best practices for every programming language and operating system I use.  You can chose to use whatever programming logic and best practices you want.  We are just pointing out a possible failure point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type `MSG /?`

For working correctly,you must add `%username%` to become `MSG %username% You need to install ImageMagick`

```bat
@echo off
REM ### check that the Image Magick program is installed
WHERE testcommand >nul 2>nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO magick wasn't found 
    MSG %username% You need to install ImageMagick
    PAUSE
)
```

Help online for this command [MSG](https://ss64.com/nt/msg.html)

Comment: I want to add that full qualified file name is `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe` and that this executable is available on 64-bit Windows only as 64-bit application. There is no `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\msg.exe` on 64-bit Windows which should be taken into account by the batch file as it can be processed by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` in which case `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe` is not found because of [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe` must be used in this case.

Comment: So better would be `if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe (%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe %username% You need to install ImageMagick) else if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe (%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe %username% You need to install ImageMagick) else (echo You need to install ImageMagick& pause)` and remove `PAUSE`. I strongly recommend to replace also `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0` by `if errorlevel 1` and `WHERE` by `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe`.

Comment: Duh!  When I looked at my other scripts I presumed %username% was a parameter that had been set higher in the script so I just ignored it.  Thanks for the answer and comments / advice.